# Difference between field widget price textfield and price with currency?

Tags: entities, commerce

What is the difference between the widget field *price textfield* and *price with currency* that you can use on the `commerce price field`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple explanation is that:

`Price textfield` only allows the user to enter a price, where the currency code is selected in the field setting, where as `Price with currency` allows the user to select both price and currency and you can setup a default currency in the field setting.